# What happens to multiprocess applications such as Postgres running in Docker?

Tags: docker

From my understanding Docker encourages a single process in a container.

How does this work and impact applications such as Postgres which can use multiple processes when querying?

Does docker restrict Postgres to only use one process or does it enable it to run multiple processes and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a technical level, when Docker creates a container, it launches a single process in that container.  In the container's process namespace, the single process that Docker launches has the process ID 1, with the rights and responsibilities that entails.  When that process exits, the container exits too.

There aren't any particular limitations on that process launching subprocesses.  If you have something like PostgreSQL, Python multiprocessing, or Apache that launches multiple child-process workers, these work fine.  These don't break the design rule that a container shouldn't do more than one thing.

The one thing to watch out for is if those subprocesses themselves launch subprocesses.  Say A starts B, which starts C, but then B exits.  The standard Unix rule is that C (the "grandchild" process) will have its parent process ID reset to 1 (the `init` process); in a Docker context this is the main container process.  If you're not prepared for this then you can have zombie processes inside your container or unexpected `SIGCHLD` notifications.  A common solution to this is to run a lightweight dedicated init process (`tini` for example) as process 1, and have it launch the main process as its only child.

Conversely, at a technical level you could run a multi-process manager like `supervisord` or, with some dedication, a heavy-weight kitchen-sink init system like `systemd` as the main container process.  This does break the "do only one thing" design rule.  These init processes take responsibility for monitoring their child processes, capturing log output, and other things that ordinarily Docker would do, and it means that if you need to delete and recreate the container (a pretty routine maintenance task) you're taking every process in the container with it.

Comment: In the A,B,C example, if B starts C and B never exists can the zombie process or any other problem still occur?

Comment: If B successfully **wait**(2)s for its children, there's not a problem.